# Is there a reason, in PHP, why one would call parent::hooks() instead of $this->hooks() in a child class?

Tags: php, class, constructor

A class I'm working with uses `parent::hooks()`, my code analysis tool suggests that `$this->hooks()` is probably a better fit.

The code looks like this:

```
class LQDM_Shortcodes_Recent_Series extends LQDM_Shortcodes_Base {
  ...
  public function __construct( $plugin ) {
    $this->run = new LQDMS_Recent_Series_Run( $plugin->sermons );
    $this->admin = new LQDMS_Recent_Series_Admin( $this->run );

    parent::hooks();
  }
}
```

The one thing I'm seeing is that the child __construct does not call the parent __construct?

Comment: You already have the same question

Comment: With calling parent::hooks() you can override method in child class and still use only code from parent.

Comment: @Akintunde-Rotimi - I don't think so...I have a similar question regarding why a function of a parent class wouldn't be found in the child class...?

Comment: @fbuchlak - In this case there is no method in the child class called hooks to override.

Comment: Maybe thats why your code analysis tool is suggesting you to use $this instead of parent. You could try to override it, do some stuff inside and than see if it still shows the message.

Comment: I would call the parent constructor (when needed) as the very first instruction.